# Selecting from multiple tables using joins and count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

1. Employee
2. issues
3. Messages

**Problem #1:**
I want to display all the employees that has an issue in Issues table. I made it so far but I need to display all his/her messages in the Messages table which indicates a column name `is_read = 0`.

```
SELECT distinct E.NAME, E.EMP_ID 
FROM ISSUES I 
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE E ON E.EMP_ID = I.RECEIVER ORDER BY E.NAME ASC
```

**Problem #2:**
For each issue in Issue table is the subject in the Messages table and I want to display the count of unread messages in the Messages table. The basis is the column name _is_read_, 0 means not opened yet and 1 is read already.

Here's how I've done it but there's something wrong in it:

```
SELECT I.SUBJECT, COUNT(M.IS_READ) AS UN_READ 
FROM MESSAGES M 
LEFT JOIN ISSUES I ON I.ID = M.ISSUE_ID
WHERE I.RECEIVER = '1234' AND M.IS_READ = 0 and M.RECEIVER = '1234' 
GROUP BY I.SUBJECT
```

Output:

```
SUBJECT                 UN_READ
Always Absent           13
Attendance Incomplete   1
Pending Requirements    6
```

Wrong, because employee *1234* has *4 issues* in Issues table and the other one has *no messages* yet and I want to still display it.

Comment: Clean up the code a bit. The second SQL snippet has mismatching aliases (`C`?)

Comment: second problem should be use c table name which is not specify

Comment: oh sorry about that.

Comment: Could you provide more information on those tables structure and some sample data?

Comment: It difficult to understand..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to display all the employees that has an issues in Issues table
>   I made it so far but I need to display all his/her messages in the
>   Messages table which indicates a column name is_read = 0.

I assume you want to display the all unread messages, but since I don't know what columns exist in the *Message* table I'll just add `M.Subject` as a dummy column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.NAME, E.EMP_ID, M.Subject 
FROM ISSUES I 
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE E ON E.EMP_ID = I.RECEIVER
LEFT JOIN MESSAGES M ON M.ISSUE_ID = I.ID AND M.IS_READ = 0
ORDER BY E.NAME ASC
```

This will list all *employees* that has *issues*, and if an unread message exist (connected to the issue) it will be displayed in *subject*.

> For each issues in Issue table is the subject in the Messages table
>   and I want to display the count of unread messages in the Messages
>   table. The basis is the column name is_read, 0 means not opened yet
>   and 1 is read already.

You are forcing your `LEFT JOIN` to become a `INNER JOIN` through the where-clause. Move some of the logic to the join instead (Like @jarlh has answered, but declaring the same receiver twice seem a bit redundant).

```
SELECT I.SUBJECT, COUNT(M.IS_READ) AS UN_READ 
FROM ISSUES I  
LEFT JOIN MESSAGES M ON M.ISSUE_ID = I.ID AND
                        M.RECEIVER = I.RECEIVER AND
                        M.IS_READ = 0
WHERE I.RECEIVER = '1234'
GROUP BY I.SUBJECT
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch outer join tables. Move table M conditions from `WHERE` to `ON` to get true outer join behavior (else it behaves as a regular inner join):

```
SELECT I.SUBJECT, COUNT(M.IS_READ) AS UN_READ 
FROM ISSUES I
  LEFT JOIN MESSAGES M
    ON I.ID = M.ISSUE_ID AND M.IS_READ = 0 and M.RECEIVER = '1234' 
WHERE I.RECEIVER = '1234'
GROUP BY I.SUBJECT
```

Comment: Thank you also for your answer.. Though answer of @mackan is more elaborated.. thank you still.